# Summing totals across multiple sheets based on a person's name

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets, with lists of names and points assigned to each name. For each individual, I want to sum all their points to determine total points. I've given two example sheets in my question, but there could be up to 4 sheets I need to include in the summation. Not all lists are in the same order, and not all names appear in every list. Appearing on each sheet is not a requirement, but I still need a total for all sheets that the individual is present.

example: Sheet 1

```
    =========== =========== ======== 
    FirstName   LastName     Points  
    =========== =========== ======== 
    Phil        Bloor           7  
    Steve       Burke          14                          
    Teresa      March          18  
    Roger       Sander          9  
    Angela      Umber           3  
    =========== =========== ========
```

Sheet 2

```
    =========== =========== ======== 
    FirstName   LastName     Points  
    =========== =========== ======== 
    Phil        Bloor           4  
    Angela      Umber          17                          
    Sarah       McComb         22  
    Roger       Sander          4  
    Shaun       Burns           8  
    =========== =========== ========
```

Thanks for any help!!!!!

Comment: Look into `3d SUMIF`

Comment: Here is a link: https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of how we can make SUMIF work across sheets conditionally (i.e., based on names present). However, here's a workaround.

Assuming you already have the First and Last Names listed in your target sheet, you can list the names of all the data sheets alongside the First and Last Name headings. You can then use a combination of SUMIFS and INDIRECT to get the results you want.

Paste this formula in C1:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(C$1&"!C:C"),INDIRECT(C$1&"!A:A"),$A2,INDIRECT(C$1&"!B:B"),$B2)
```

The cells have been frozen so that they can be copied to the other target cells without modifying the formula.

This will fetch you person-wise amounts from each sheet. You can then have a total column at the end in the target sheet, like this:

```
+---+-----------+----------+--------+--------+-------+
|   |     A     |    B     |   C    |   D    |   E   |
+---+-----------+----------+--------+--------+-------+
| 1 | FirstName | LastName | Sheet1 | Sheet2 | Total |  <-- Headings
+---+-----------+----------+--------+--------+-------+
| 2 | Phil      | Bloor    | 7      | 4      | 11    |
| 3 | Angela    | Umber    | 3      | 17     | 20    |
| 4 | Sarah     | McComb   | 0      | 22     | 22    |
| 5 | Roger     | Sander   | 9      | 4      | 13    |
| 6 | Shaun     | Burns    | 0      | 8      | 8     |
| 7 | Steve     | Burke    | 14     | 0      | 14    |
| 8 | Teresa    | March    | 18     | 0      | 18    |
+---+-----------+----------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Create tables of each data range in each sheet

Highlight first table and go to Get & Transform (or PowerQuery tab) and click From Table and add the tabl then select Close and load to "Only create a connection".

Repeat for other tables.

Then go to New Query > Combine Queries > Append > Three or more tables > select your tables you just added via queries i.e. Press add until all  tables move to right hand side.

Add column tab > custom column > Give new column name as "FullName" and formula as FirstName & LastName > click ok > Transform tab > Group By > FullName.

Then input for New column name = "TotalPoints", Operation = Sum, Column = "Points"

Home tab > Close and load.

You will have a new sheet containing one table created from all the others and which sums the number of points for each combination of FirstName and LastName.

There will be a workbook query called Append1 which you can refresh by clicking the green arrow. This will update the summary table for any new data entered into the tables in the other sheets.

Answer (score 1):

With `SUMIFS`, `SUMPRODUCT`, and `INDIRECT`, you can make this to work with some tweak.

Assuming you have the names listed, here is how you can do if you were to put the formula from `cell C2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$E$2:$E$3&"'!"&"$C$2:$C$100"),INDIRECT("'"&$E$2:$E$3&"'!"&"$A$2:$A$100"),A2,INDIRECT("'"&$E$2:$E$3&"'!"&"$B$2:$B$100"),B2))
```

[image]

Basically, the `INDIRECT` with `SUMIFS` will aggregate all the sheets you need to evaluate and make it to an array with `SUMPRODUCT`.  Hope this helps.